# I want to merge or I should say update multiple jsonb column in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column as sensor_info which is of jsonb type column. The column can contain like this

```json
{"temp":54, "humidity":34}
{"pressure":34}
{"switch":"on"}
{"temp":60, "humidity":78}
```

This can consider as multiple records of one column. This records I have to group them together into one column with latest key-value.
like-

```json
{"temp":60, "humidity":78, "pressure":34, "switch":"on"}
```

I tried with `json_agg` but it is returning something like `[{"temp":54, "humidity":34},{"pressure":34},{"switch":"on"},{"temp":60, "humidity":78}]`

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this. But you can easily defined your own:

```
create aggregate jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb) 
(
  sfunc = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
  stype = jsonb
);
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
select jsonb_merge_agg(sensor_info)
from the_table;
```

A JSON value can only contain each key once and the aggregate will keep the "last one". If you want to control which key is the "last" one, you need to and an order by, e.g. `jsonb_merge_agg(sensor_info order by created_at)`

Comment: This actually solved my issue thank you. And also thank you for guiding.